# Is there a limit to the Height of a Webview Control?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing an app which extensively uses the WebView Control. 
The thing is that I need to set dynamically the Height property of the WebView control so that I can capture its whole content with WebviewBrush as follow:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="webViewScroll" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="1200" MaxWidth="1200">
     <WebView  Name="mywebview"/>
</Grid>
```

And somewhere inside the `NavigationCompleted` event handler of the WebView

```cs
webView.Height = height; // <--- setting the height of the WebView
WebViewBrush b = new WebViewBrush();
b.SetSource(webView);
b.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
b.Redraw();
var rectangle = new Rectangle { Width = 1200, Height = height };
rectangle.Fill = b;
```

For a small value of height (something less than 6000), it works fine but for values greater than 6000 (sometimes it's 8000), it seems that the WebView control is broken and I got a lot of blank spaces in the WebviewBrush.
Did I miss something that I need to do prior to setting the height or is it a normal behavior? 
If it is normal behavior, could you please advise another method to capture the content of a **long** web page?

**EDIT**

You may check a demo app [here](https://github.com/jsami/WebViewResize). 
And a video showing the behavior that I described can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_L-DZH_uXzk). As you can see in this video, the webview behaves strangely starting at a certain value of the height (the scroll is not smooth anymore for example), and the brush is not fully drawn.

Thank you in advance for your precious help :)

Regards

Comment: For WebViewBrush  could not render large than 6000, I'm afraid I could not reproduce your problem, could you mind share the demo for me?

Comment: Hello @NicoZhu. Thank you very much for looking at it :)
Yes, effectively I've followed the method used in the link you shared above but this also sets a value to the height of the WebView, and I'm having the issue that I described in my question when the height is quite big.

Comment: I have added a link to a demo app and a link to a video showing the issue I am talking about.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I got it, I will test it.

Comment: I run your code and it works in my side with out blank part when the webview height large than 8000, and could you test in other computer?

Comment: Hello. Yes, I've already tested on another computer and I got the blank all the time.

Comment: Please share more info about your OS version? I will test in the same environment.

Comment: Hello. This is my OS info: **Windows 10 Pro, Version 1909**

Comment: I have test your demo in 1903 1909 and 2004(insinder preview), I can reproduce this only in 1909, and it looks fixed in 2004, please pay a attention to the following os update.